# Terminology of class components

Tags: java, terminology

Could you tell me what is the name of `ArrayList<Image>` (4<sup>th</sup> line) in Java terminology in the following code?

```
public class ImageCollection {
  private  int imageNum;                           // field
  private  String name;                            // field
  ArrayList<Image> album = new ArrayList<Image>(); // ???

  public ImageCollection(String n, int numIm) {    // constructor
    name = n;
    imageNum = numIm;
  }

  public set(String n) {                           // method
    name = n;
  }
```

Comment: What do you want to say by "the name" ?

Comment: in listing I wrote the constructor, method, two fields, but how can we call the 4th line?

Comment: `ArrayList<Image> album` is another field of your `ImageCollection` class, you just haven't provide the visibility, so it will be public for all clases in the same package but private for classes outside the package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
name - field of type String
album - field of type ArrayList<Image>, you can read it as list of images
```

Comment: `ArrayList` with the `Image` class template

Answer (score 0):

That's a field declaration. However, rather than being initialized with the default value (`null`), it's initialized as an empty ArrayList that may contain Image objects.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList is a "Collection" field, more specifically a List

Within the code block, it is called a field

Answer (score 0):

the `album` variable is list of Images - ArrayList is one of implementation of the `List` object

See [Arraylist javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)